# MySQL select a date between two dates using the time now

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select a row from a table assuming that the kick off time is within an hour's range of the current time.

The table is just an id and a datetime field.

```
SELECT * FROM kick_offs WHERE NOW() BETWEEN (DATE_SUB(`time`, INTERVAL 30 MINUTES)) AND (DATE_ADD(`time`, INTERVAL 30 MINUTES))

SELECT * FROM kick_offs WHERE `time` BETWEEN (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTES)) AND (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTES))
```

These two queries both fail. I'm not really sure why. The server is running MySQL 5.0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I appreciate that I may be being dense because it's late and I've been working all day, but a downvote without a comment isn't helpful.

Comment: I don't currently have a MySQL db available, but I believe it's `MINUTE` - not `MINUTES`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where you got your SQL from, but this should do it I think.

```
  SELECT * FROM kick_offs WHERE `time` < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND `time`>= NOW()
```

See:
[Display rows from MySQL where a datetime is within the next hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642885/display-rows-from-mysql-where-a-datetime-is-within-the-next-hour)